# Flash (AS3) - Mass Tab Enabling

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, tabindex, cs4

I'm building a flash application and on one frame I have a number of controls that pressing tab will highlight and allow to be selectable (accessibility).

When I select one of the controls the background has an alpha shape over the top of it (initially set to 0), it will slightly dim the original screen and a new control appears in front (on top) with information (this box can be closed and the original screen is tweened from it's dimmed alpha state back to normal).

My issue is, I would like to stop the controls on the original screen to be tabbed through (I only want the pressing of tab to highlight the new windows buttons).

I know I can use `tabEnabled` on each single control, but is it possible to simply set a top level controls `tabEnabled` to `false` and for it to disable all the tab indexes of its own children.

Because of the variety of differing levels or child controls within each movie clip control beneath my top level I want to just set the top level. Would I have to write a recursive function to complete such simple functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tabChildren = false](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#tabChildren) ;)

Comment: Doh! Nice one. As if I couldn't find that before asking here.